# How to make a phone call using intent in Android without permission?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-phone-call

My app uses the android permission action_dial.
How to change the code so it doesn't need permission?
i need to be able to call witout permission

this is the code:

Its not my fault this post is full of code.

---

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        // Older Version No need to request Permission
        String dial = "tel:" + phoneNo;
        fragment.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse(dial)));
    } else {
        // Need to request Permission
        if (fragment.getActivity() != null) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(fragment.getActivity(), Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                fragment.requestPermissions(new String[]{
                        Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE
                }, Constants.REQUEST_CODE__PHONE_CALL_PERMISSION);
            } else {
                String dial = "tel:" + phoneNo;
                fragment.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse(dial)));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

---

```
                                             int[] grantResults, Fragment fragment, String phoneNo) {
    if (requestCode == Constants.REQUEST_CODE__PHONE_CALL_PERMISSION) {
        if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            callPhone(fragment, phoneNo);
        } else {
            Utils.psLog("Permission not Granted");
        }
```

---

---

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        // Older Version No need to request Permission
        String dial = "tel:" + phoneNo;
        activity.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(dial)));
    } else {
        // Need to request Permission
        if (activity != null) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                activity.requestPermissions(new String[]{
                        Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE
                }, Constants.REQUEST_CODE__PHONE_CALL_PERMISSION);
            } else {
                String dial = "tel:" + phoneNo;
                activity.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(dial)));
            }
        }
    }
```

---

Comment: You need to remove the permission tag from manifest, then remove the code related to permission from class (checkSelfPermission & requestPermissions...) then use only startActivity for Intent.ACTION_DIAL, check code below or it's also inside yours in if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {}

Answer (score 3):

You don't need permission to execute that phone call intent.

```
/**
 * Make a phone call. Send to the phone app
 *
 * @param phoneNumber the phone number to call
 */
private fun performPhoneCall(phoneNumber: String) {
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL)
    intent.data = Uri.parse("tel:$phoneNumber")
    try {
        context.startActivity(intent)
    } catch (ex: Exception) {
        displayErrorMessage()
    }
}
```

Comment: this works, ACTION_CALL need permission in xml.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like so:

```
Intent intentDial = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel:" + "123456789"));
context.startActivity(intentDial);
```

But it will navigate user to the default call dialer app and pass it the phone number so the user should push the call button to make a call. It doesn't make a call directly.

Comment: thanks this code replace with what code in my codes?

Comment: It doesn't matter. Everywhere that you want. Also, you don't need to grant run time permission. @adp

Answer (score 0):

Direct Call cant be made without permission.
You can open the dialer on top of the app with the needed number, the user should next click on the green call button.
To do this use this code

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNumberStr));

startActivity(callIntent);
```